# Webmapping js library with best support to WFS-T

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, wfs-t, openlayers-2

I've tried to use WFS-T in ol3 but it was really a hard task, it seems that WFS-T is badly undocumented feature and it's much complicated to implement, and i'm looking for recommandations concerning the easiest manner to deal with WFS-T, and what js library to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment I still prefer OpenLayers2. You can find a nice tutorial here:
 http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

or even have a look at the "official" openlayers-example:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

Of course you can also use Leaflet but Openlayers has a much better support for OGC-compliant services. In case you want to have a look at leaflet-wfs-t:

Building wfs-t-support in Leaflet from scratch:

http://blog.georepublic.info/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/

or the leaflet-wfs-t-plugin:
https://github.com/flatrockgeo/leaflet.wfs-t